# (BIND9) Domains within certain Zone stop resolving randomly / intermittently

Tags: ubuntu, bind, internal-dns, dns-zone

I've been stuck for a while with an error related to bind9 and particular domains within a zone. Sometimes the resolution of one or more random domains within the zone ("errorzone", let's say) stops working, affecting one day example1.errorzone and another day example4.errorzone, example5.errorzone, etc. The rest of my zones worksperfectly all the time.

The logs says: *named[20450]: client 192.168.50.20#64165 (example3.errorzone): query (cache) 'example3.errorzone/A/IN' denied*

The solution right now consists in restarting Bind9 service but I can't afford it anymore. I could not find the issue or the original cause.

Current named.conf.options (edited Networks and so on):

```
acl myLAN { 
 172.20.0.0/16;  
 192.168.50.0/24;  
 };  

options {   
 directory "/etc/bind/";  
 forwarders {  
   8.8.8.8;  
   dnsISP1;
   dnsISP2;  
   10.20.30.40;  
 };  

allow-query {  
  myLAN;    
  };  

allow-recursion {  
  myLAN;  
 };
```

};*

Errorzone named.conf:

```
zone "errorzone" {  
type forward;  
forwarders {10.20.30.40;};
};
```

Bind9 version: 9.9.5-3ubuntu0.18-Ubuntu.
EDIT: The forwarder it's not under our administration, it's an external DNS of our ISP provider to resolv this "errorzone".

Could anybody give me a hand? I ran out of ideas.
Thanks, any info will be really appreciated.

Comment: Since you forward the queries for "errorzone", shouldn't you look at the configuration of the DNS server with IP address 10.20.30.40?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that the forwarder is not under our control, it's an external DNS. I'll edit the thread.

Comment: I would check with the external DNS provider. Or you could do the lookups yourself if that's possible.